# Rails helpers and plugin helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I override a method of community engine in my app helper.
The problem I am facing is in community engine plugin the method is in base helper and in my app helper it is in some other helper.
Since rails search methods in helper in alphabetical order of the helper names the method in community engine plugin is being called always.

Is there a  way to tell rails to first search in app helpers and if the method is not present in app helpers then search in plugins?

Comment: Code samples please... Although, why don't you just rename your method?

Comment: Monkeypaching if you want to override the engine's helper. Not a very good practice but it works sometime.

Comment: When I have my method in base helper or application helper it works but the problem comes only when I have it in some other helper whose name starts greater than b (i.e c, d,....). This is because base helper of the plugin comes first in alphabetical order. Any way to first search all the app helpers for the methods if not present in app helper then search in plugin helper?